# AWS RDS - HIPAA compliant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm planning to have Oracle on AWS.

Is Oracle RDS HIPAA compliant? How can I make it HIPAA compliant?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the law, not programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer just recently changed. RDS is now HIPAA compliant, per their documentation/FAQ:

> What Services Can I Use in My AWS Account if I Have a BAA with AWS?
>
> Customers may use any AWS service in an account designated as a HIPAA account, but they should only process, store and transmit PHI in the HIPAA-eligible services defined in the BAA. There are nine HIPAA-eligible services today, including Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon EBS, Amazon EC2, Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR), Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), Amazon Glacier, **Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) [MySQL and Oracle engines]**, Amazon Redshift, and Amazon S3.

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-compliance/#What_Services_Can_I_Use_in_My_AWS_Account_if_I_Have_a_BAA_with_AWS?)

Answer (score 2):

@Dang

There is no AWS offical documentation that says RDS can be made HIPAA compliant. Instead EC2, S3 and EBS are known services. The way to get HIPAA compliant for your AWS services follow this:

- Customers must identify to AWS each account to be covered by the BAA
  as a 'HIPAA Account'.
- Customers may process, store or transmit PHI only on EC2, S3 and EBS.
- Customers must use Dedicated instances for PHI data -
  http://aws.amazon.com/dedicated-instances/
- Customers must use VPC
- Customers must encrypt all PHI in accordance with certain minimum
  encryption standards
- Customers may use any AWS service in their 'HIPAA Account' for data
  that is not PHI

So, to get a BAA agreement from AWS you'll need dedicated instances running in a VPC, not the "classic" EC2. (Pricing for dedicated instances has come down a lot since the very beginning.)

I cannot comment about RDS for sure. What I know RDS can be made quite secure, using SSL over port 443.

What I suggest that If you are an authorized AWS customer, speak to AWS customer care executive as they are the best to validate my answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the whitepaper released by Amazon Web Services on December 2015 (link mentioned below )
Amazon RDS for Oracle and Amazon RDS for Mysql are available for use under HIPAA standards once you sign an Business associate agreement and your account is designated as an "HIPAA account" 
Link to the white paper - https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_HIPAA_Compliance_Whitepaper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS is an [AWS HIPAA-Eligible Service](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-eligible-services-reference/) meaning that it can be used with

In order to be HIPAA compliant in AWS, your team must do the following:

1. Sign a Business Associates Agreement (BAA) with AWS. This agreement outlines the HIPAA security responsibilities shared between the cloud provider and the cloud customer
2. Adopt appropriate administrative policies and procedures
3. Implement all necessary security configuration for individual cloud services, such as RDS, EC2, and S3. Security standards include configuring safeguards around encryption, backup and disaster recovery, and access control.

You can take a look at this guide to [utilizing Amazon RDS in a HIPAA compliant manner](https://www.dashsdk.com/docs/aws/hipaa/amazon-rds/).